# Slider in a clip path in Firefox, Opera,

Tags: html, css, svg, clip, clip-path

I'm currently working on a onepage site with an image slider in a clip path. Example here:
http://grafomantestsite3.be/.

Here is a small piece of code:

```css
#slide1 {
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 0px !important;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 500px, 100% 450px, 100% 0px, 0px 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="slide1">
  <div class="ccm-image-slider-container">
    <div class="ccm-custom-style-slide1">
      <!-- here you have the slider -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The slider is generated using a block in Concrete5.  So the HTML code for the image slider is generated using a script.

This seems to work in Chrome, but not in Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer...

Is there an easy way to fix this? I know about the SVG method but that doesn't seem to work since you need to set the background images within the HTML? And here this is not possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

So i tried the SVG method and added this to the body of the HTML:

```css
#slide1 {
  height: 500px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 0px !important;
  clip-path: polygon(0px 500px, 100% 450px, 100% 0px, 0px 0px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 500px, 100% 450px, 100% 0px, 0px 0px);
  /*Firefox*/
  clip-path: url("#clipPolygon");
}
```

```html
<div id="slide1">
  <div class="ccm-image-slider-container">
    <div class="ccm-custom-style-slide1">
      <!-- here you have the slider -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<svg width="0" height="0">
  <clipPath id="clipPolygon">
    <polygon points="0 500,960 450,960 0,0 0">
    </polygon>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

This however does not seem to work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `-webkit-clip-path` only applies to webkit based browsers (Chrome/Safari/Opera).  If you want to use clip paths on Firefox, you'll need to also use `clip-path`.

See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

The other problem is that Firefox doesn't yet support CSS shapes like `polygon()` for clip paths.  You'll need to define an polygon in an SVG and reference that with `clip-path: url(#id-of-your-polygon-element)`.

Comment: I tried experimenting with the SVG, but can't seem to get it to work. Where exaclty do i add the SVG element? In the header? Or does this not matter?

Comment: I can't seem to apply the SVG to the div #slide1

Comment: The SVG should be inline in your HTML. There is an example here: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: I edited the code above (that is not currently working)

Comment: It's working fine for me.  If you give `#slide1` a background color so it is actually visible, you can see the clip is happening.

Comment: Okay, so i got it working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgygPB
Now when you check http://grafomantestsite3.be/ you see there i want to use this for a slider. This means i do not control the control within the clipped SVG. I've searched around the net but did not found an easy solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98350/discussion-between-jacob-van-achter-and-paul-lebeau).